# Using Google's speech-to-text API for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-to-text

I am currently a beginner to python and I am building a car as a first project. I wanted to implement Google's speech-to-text API to control the directions of the car, but it's extremely slow to output the text. I was wondering if there are any alternatives to this API or if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Which Pi model are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi's CPU is not fast enough, therefore, you must use the internet connection for the sending voice and take feedback API. In bellow link give implementation how to Using the Web Speech API on Raspberry Pi.

https://www.brandoncorlett.com/blog/article/using-the-web-speech-api-on-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

We are using pocketsphinx and kaldi on a Raspberry Pi 3 without problems. The Raspi is fast enough to do decent offline "Speech To Text" - even the recognition is acceptable. Not on par with Alexa or Google, but close - especially if you use kws (Keyword Search) mode with pocketsphinx.

The August issue of MagPi has a nice article about Raspberry Speech Recognition (Page 23 ff). Get's you started.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi72.pdf